# Django: urls.py giving No Reverse Match error

Tags: django, django-authentication, lockout

I installed `django-axes` which allows you to set a url to redirect to upon 5 login failures. I added this line to **settings.py** per the [documentation](https://django-axes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/4_configuration.html):

```
AXES_LOCKOUT_URL = 'account-locked'
```

I then added this line to **users/urls.py**:

```
path('account/locked/?username=<str>', user_views.account_locked, name='account-locked'),
```

When i input 5 incorrect username/password combos in the login screen, it attempts to redirect me, but I get this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /login/
Reverse for 'account-locked?username=user2' not found. 'account-locked?username=user2' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`django-axes` setting `AXES_LOCKOUT_URL` probably expects the path URL (not the path name)

So can you try changing `AXES_LOCKOUT_URL` like below:

```
AXES_LOCKOUT_URL = 'login/account/locked/'
```

And your path should look like this

```
path('account/locked/', user_views.account_locked, name='account-locked'),
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i tried that but I got a 404 error: `Request URL: http://localhost:8000/login/account/locked/?username=user2`

Comment: @Tom Ah i see then it expects with "login/"  prefix for some reason. Can you try changing this setting to AXES_LOCKOUT_URL = 'login/account/locked/'

Comment: I still get the same 404 error with `AXES_LOCKOUT_URL = 'login/account/locked/'`. Would it have something to do with the parameters? Eg) `Reverse for 'account-locked?username=user2' not found. 'account-locked?username=user2' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Comment: @Tom, yes I've edited the answer. The queryparams shouldn't be written to path URL, this syntax meant to work with URL parameters not the queryparams.

Comment: The answer you posted is very close, but I had to set `AXES_LOCKOUT_URL = 'account/locked/'` in settings.py, and `path('login/account/locked/', user_views.account_locked, name='account-locked'),` in urls.py. I'll mark your answer as correct